# Custom CSS for a Fixed DIV

Tags: html, css, fixed

I have coded a CSS for a notification bar which slides down when mouse is hovered. The news (text) scrolls using `<marquee>` tag. The box is currently rectangular in shape. I have attached the screenshot on mouse hover and without it. However I want to have a custom shape for the bar.

So on idle state it must only show the notification button, but on hover the whole bar must slide down. How do I achieve it.

Given Below is the CSS Code

```
#feedback { 
        height: 20px; 
        width: 400px; 
        position: fixed; 
        z-index: 2500;
        right:0%;
        background:#F29300;
        border:#0F0; border:thick;
        transition:all 0.2s ease-out;
        -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease-out;
        -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-out;
        -o-transition:all 0.2s ease-out;
        transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(-180deg) translateY(-10px);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(-180deg) translateY(-10px);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(-180deg) translateY(-10px);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(-180deg) translateY(-10px);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(-180deg) translateY(-10px);

    }
    #feedback:hover { 
        transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(-180deg) translateY(2px);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(-180deg) translateY(2px);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(-180deg) translateY(2px);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(-180deg) translateY(2px);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(-180deg) translateY(2px);

    }
```

And this is the HTML Code

```
<div id="feedback" class="feedback">
            <marquee scrollamount="3" ><font size="+1">My CUstom text</font></marquee>
        </div>
```

Current
[image: On Hover]

I need to have like the one shown below.
Without Hover
[image]

On Hover the div must slide down 
[image]

I want to get this custom shape to work. How do I do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your specific question is not very clear.  However, this is an example of how you could make a simple notification bar:

```css
#notification {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  top: -20px;
  background: orange;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  }

#hover {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background: orange;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  }

#hover:hover {
  position: fixed;
  background: orange;
  width: 100px;
  height: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  }

#notification:hover {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  top: 0;
  background: orange;
  text-align: center;
  }

#hover:hover + #notification {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  top: 0;
  background: orange;
  text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<div id="hover">Hover Me!</div><div id="notification">You have been notified!</div>
```

Comment: Now that works perfect.. Even better than what i expected..

Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem.  The best part is that this works on mobile devices, too.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do this like this

CSS:

```
.feedback {
  width: 400px; 
  position: fixed; 
  z-index: 2500; 
  text-align:center;
}
.feedback marquee{
  background:#F29300;
  height:5px;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:block;
  margin:0;
  transition-property: height;
 -webkit-transition-property: height;
 -moz-transition-property: height;
 transition-duration: .3s;
 -webkit-transition-duration: .3s;
 -moz-transition-duration: .3s;
}

 .feedback button{
  background: #F29300;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
}


.feedback:hover marquee{
         height:30px;
}
```

and HTML

```
<div id="feedback" class="feedback">
  <marquee scrollamount="3" ><font size="+1">My CUstom text</font></marquee>
  <button>Notification</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Try not to suggest poorly supported code, even if the asker is using it. [marguee](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee#Browser_compatibility) has almost no support, and should never be used.